# Using a System.Diagnostics.Process to Launch a Third Party Application

Tags: c#, process, singleton

All, I am developing an application that needs to launch another application at run-time. To launch the third-party app I am using `System.Diagnostics.Process` and to ensure I never launch the third-party application twice I employ a singleton pattern.

The singleton is working is required, but `Process.Start()` method is not. That is although I am getting the same `Process` object returned from the singleton, `Start()` is launching another instance of the third-part app.

From [MSDN - Process.Start() page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e8zac0ca.aspx):

```
"Starts (or reuses) the process resource that is specified by the StartInfo property 
of this Process component and associates it with the component."
```

suggest that it should reuse the instance of the `Process`. What am I missing?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Do you check if the last process is still running before you call `Start()` again? (Using the `HasExited` property.)

Comment: I can, but the confusing thing is that the documentation suggests that this will be handeled by the call to `Start()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the function I use to start third party applications:

```
    public static void ProcessStart(string ExecutablePath, string sArgs, bool bWait)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        proc.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
        proc.StartInfo.FileName = ExecutablePath;

        if(sArgs.Length > 0)
            proc.StartInfo.Arguments = sArgs;


        proc.Start();

        if(bWait)
            proc.WaitForExit();

        if(ProcessLive(ExecutablePath))
            return true;
        else
            return false;               

    }
```

ExecutablePath: Full path to the executable

sArgs: Command line arguments

bWait: Wait for the process to exit

In my case I use a secondary function to determine if the process is already running.  This is not exactly what you are looking for, but it will still work:

```
    public static bool ProcessLive(string ExecutablePath)
    {
        try
        {

            string strTargetProcessName = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(ExecutablePath);

            System.Diagnostics.Process[] Processes = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName(strTargetProcessName);

            foreach(System.Diagnostics.Process p in Processes)
            {
                foreach(System.Diagnostics.ProcessModule m in p.Modules)
                {
                    if(ExecutablePath.ToLower() == m.FileName.ToLower())
                        return true;
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception){}

        return false;

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should consider using `Process.GetProcessesByName` to understand if that application you're launching is already running.

Comment: +1 Thanks this is an options, but like I said in the comment above. MSDN suggests that this will be handled by `Start()`?

Answer (score 0):

use it as follows

```
Process[] chromes = Process.GetProcessesByName("ProcessName"); to check whether ur process is already running or not. Based on the u can use the process already running.
```